# PHP syntax error for outputting value

Tags: php, syntax

**How do I write this with emphasis on:**

```
isset($fields['firstName']) 
  ? ' value=" ' . e( $fields['firstName'] ) . '"' 
  : '' ?>
```

**From this:**
(this is from a HTML file that contains php)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" <?php echo isset($fields['firstName']) ? ' value="' . e($fields['firstName']) . '"' : '' ?>>
```

**Into this:** (this is from a php file that contains html)

```
$output .= '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name">';
```

The goal here is to get the same syntax with the second statement because I am going to return the $output variable in a function. Therefore I can't use the first statement and want to convert the syntax. Thank you in advance for the help

This is the part of the function where I need the first statement in ( focus is on the name input value):

```
function get_special_promos_landing_html ($id, $item, $errors, $success, $fields) {
    $output = '';

    $output.= '<form name="couponForm" class="couponForm" method="post"  action="mail/coupon_form.php" novalidate>';
    $output.= '<div class="row">';
    $output.= '<div class="col-md-12">';
    $output.= '<div class="row control-group">';
    $output.= '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">';
    $output.= '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name. **need the above syntax here to retain value when I have an error**. ">';
    //if name error
    if(!empty($errors['name'])) {
        $output.= '<div class="error_notice">';
        $output.= '<ul>';
        $output.= '<li>' . $errors["name"] . '</li> <!--Lists down errors-->';
        $output.= '</ul>';
        $output.= '</div>';
    }   
    $output.= '</div>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    $output.= '<div class="col-md-2">';
    $output.= '<div class="row control-group">';
    $output.= '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls text-center">';
    $output.= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme-dark">Submit</button>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    $output.= '<div id="success"></div>';
    $output.= '</form>';

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: what does `e($fields['firstName'])` do?

Comment: @BagusTesa - I'm guessing it just outputs the input, you'd have a better name for something that sanitized, etc... But I guess this cause be has to cancat his content.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$output .= '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" ' . (isset($fields['firstName']) ? ' value="' . e($fields['firstName']) . '"' : '')  . '>';
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Its suppose to retain the input value once I press on submit but it doesn't.

Comment: @Roger If you're including a `submit` in this system as well can you show us __all__ of your code? Instead of making us guess, thanks! :)

Comment: @Roger, it should work in the code you shared... do you tried checking the values of the variable `$fields`? Try with a `var_dump($fields);` in the beginning of the function just to be sure if the value is really set there.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear where you get the values from, and put it into your function get_special_promos_landing_html().

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" <?php echo isset($fields['firstName']) ? ' value="' . e($fields['firstName']) . '"' : '' ?>>
```

For the above code if you are using a submit button and you want the values to be retained you need to do something like this somewhere within your codes where you call the function.

```
if ($_POST) {
$somevariable = '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="' . $_POST['firstName'] . '">
```

}

Because upon submit your fields will automatically clear. Using $_POST you get your values back into your fields.

Alternative you can redirect to the same page again after submit so your values get reloaded again. You may add this to the end after all your insert to database statements etc

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$output= '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name">';
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  placeholder="First Name" 
  name="firstName" 
  id="firstName" 
<?php 
  echo isset($fields['firstName']) ? 
    ' value="' . e($fields['firstName']) . '"' 
    : '' 
?>>
```

You have done the incorrect syntax for a `ternary operator` being used in an echo string, the ternary operator (when used in echo/print) should be represented like so:

```
echo (true ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

And not:

```
echo true ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
```

I'm sure you can see what's wrong there, and using `isset` just returns a `true OR false` depending on the data.

So just add the brackets around the echo, like so:

```
<?php 
  echo (isset($fields['firstName']) ? 
    ' value="' . e($fields['firstName']) . '"' 
    : '')
?>>
```

And that should fix it. `:~)`

**What you asked for:**

```
$output .= 
"<input type='text'class='form-control' placeholder='First Name' name='firstName' id='firstName'"
. (isset($fields['firstName']) ? " value='{$fields['firstName']}'");
```

**(If errors please report in comments, thanks)**

If using PHP & HTML (PHP as the var container) I recommend using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), as it makes your code look cleaner and easier to read, **Example:** (PHP's string interpolation is not strong enough to use Ternary operators inside of HEREDOC, but, you can set the value beforehand, also, if there's errors with the Heredoc, let me know since Heredoc is a pain.)

```
$value = (isset($fields['firstName']) ? "value='{$fields['firstName']'" : "");

$output .= <<<IDENTIFIER_FOR_HEREDOC;
  <input 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="First Name" 
    name="firstName" 
    id="firstName" 
    value="{$value}"
IDENTIFIER_FOR_HEREDOC;
```

Comment: I am trying to include this parcel of code in a function and return it. So I can't use echo. That is why I use "output.=" but my syntax won't work.

Comment: So, try replacing `echo` with `$output .=` and let me know how that goes, let me know the error message if you get one. `:-)`

Comment: Updated answer @Roger

Comment: I posted the partial function. Basically I just need the code in the first statement and need to put it in that function but I can't because I get an error.